# HTML: td-iframe comes inside the table. Can it be displayed outside in the whitespace?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Here is my style.css(From jssfiddle)

```
#comments {
  background: #fff
}

iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1200px;
  border: 0;
}

#comment-wrap {
  background: #fff;
  position: relative
}

#comments #comment-wrap {
  display: none;
  z-index: 5;
  padding: 10px
}

#comments:hover #comment-wrap {
  display: block
}
```

Here is my jquery.js(from jsfiddle)

```
hover = function() {
  if (!document.body.currentStyle) return;
  var DIVcomments = document.getElementById('comments');
  var DIVcomment_wrap = document.getElementById('comment-wrap');
  DIVcomments.onmouseover = function() {
    DIVcomment_wrap.style.display = 'block';
  }
  DIVcomments.onmouseout = function() {
    DIVcomment_wrap.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
window.onload = hover;
```

Here is the html that is made from a text file. The last column width is 1280px even though I asked it to be only for the iframe. When I hover on the wikipedia text, the display is within the columns making it very annoying and unable to hover on to the next record. I did search online and on stack overflow but couldn't find a valid settings for my td tag. Any pointers are appreciated to take the display outside the columns?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="jquery.js"></script>

<html>
<style type=text/css>
            table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            }
            </style>
   <body>
<table>
<th>HEADING1</th>
<th>HEADING2</th>
<th>HEADING3</th>
<th>HEADING4</th>
<tr>
<td>sam</td>
<td> newyork</td>
<td> 1345B</td>
<td style="width: 1280px"> <div id="comments"> <a href="#"     class="btn">Wikipedia</a> <div id="comment-wrap"> <iframe     src="http://wikipedia.com" width="1280" height="720"></iframe> </div>     </div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>msnam</td>
<td> newsdfyork</td>
<td> 1345B</td>
<td> 783473</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>sadfm</td>
<td> newysdfork</td>
<td> 1345B</td>
<td> 7sdf83473</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>sam</td>
<td> newysdfork</td>
<td> 1345B</td>
<td> 783sdf473</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>sasdfm</td>
<td> newysdfork</td>
<td> 1345B</td>
<td> 7834sdf73</td>
</tr>
</table>
   </body>
</html>
```

[image: Before Hovering]

[image: During Hovering]

Comment: So the iFrame is within the table? You can style the `<iframe>` element **itself**, but unfortunately, it's impossible to style anything **within** an `<iframe>` without access to the iFrame's CSS.

Comment: So the style.css is different from the iframe's css?

Comment: Yes. Wikipedia has their own `style.css`. When you are utilising an iFrame, you're also pulling through everything on that page, including loading their CSS files. Considering anyone can iFrame anyone else's website, you can't modify **their** CSS as a security measure. What you are trying to do is impossible to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Is there a way to change the CSS or JS above such that instead of hovering and displaying - when clicked and popup the iframe and when clicked again close the iframe?

Comment: Yes, that is absolutely possible, as you're only making a change to behaviour on **your** site. Simply make a button that launches the iFrame in a modal popup. I personally usually use Bootstrap and do it with [**Bootstrap Modals**](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp). If you're not using Bootstrap (or a similar framework), you'll have to make your own modal.

Comment: Thanks. It works - https://codepen.io/filippoq/pen/QwogWz/

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want "flying" iframe

```js
var DIVcomments = document.getElementById('comments');
var DIVcomment_wrap = document.getElementById('comment-wrap');
DIVcomments.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  var pos = DIVcomments.getBoundingClientRect();
  DIVcomment_wrap.style.top = pos.top + "px";
  DIVcomment_wrap.style.left = (pos.left + 70) + "px";
  DIVcomment_wrap.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].style.width = (document.body.offsetWidth - pos.left - 90) + "px";
  DIVcomment_wrap.style.display = 'block';
});

DIVcomments.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  DIVcomment_wrap.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
#comments {
  background: #fff
}

iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1200px;
  border: 0;
}

#comment-wrap {
  background: #fff;
  position: relative
}

#comments #comment-wrap {
  display: none;
  z-index: 5;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}

#comments:hover #comment-wrap {
  display: block
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

iframe {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <th>HEADING1</th>
  <th>HEADING2</th>
  <th>HEADING3</th>
  <th>HEADING4</th>
  <tr>
    <td>sam</td>
    <td> newyork</td>
    <td> 1345B</td>
    <td style="width: 1280px">
      <div id="comments"> <a href="#" class="btn">Wikipedia</a>
        <div id="comment-wrap">
          <iframe src="https://www.wikipedia.org/" width="1280" height="720"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>msnam</td>
    <td> newsdfyork</td>
    <td> 1345B</td>
    <td> 783473</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>sadfm</td>
    <td> newysdfork</td>
    <td> 1345B</td>
    <td> 7sdf83473</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>sam</td>
    <td> newysdfork</td>
    <td> 1345B</td>
    <td> 783sdf473</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>sasdfm</td>
    <td> newysdfork</td>
    <td> 1345B</td>
    <td> 7834sdf73</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. But the last column width has to be similar to the other three columns. The hovering popup window should not interfere with the columns. But unfortunately, even your idea still puts the pop up on the columns making it hard to hover. Appreciate your time.